# Power apps, If statement has invalid arguments

Tags: powerapp

I am trying to apply a filter to my browse gallery.
My dropdown is supposed to filter it based on Approved, New, In Progress or Rejected. Which I have linked to my datasource.

`Distinct('ATP Request Change',Status)`

This is the if statement im using in my Items property in Browse Gallery:

```
If(
    Dropdown1.Selected.Result = "Approved",
    (SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'ATP Request Change'],
            Lower('Initiator Name'.Email) = Lower(User().Email) Or IsBlank('Initiator Name'.Email) Or Lower('Control Owner A'.Email) = Lower(User().Email) Or Lower('SOX OG Approver'.Value) = Lower(User().Email) Or Lower('SOX Testing Approver'.Value) = Lower(User().Email) && StartsWith(
                Control,
                TextSearchBox1.Text
            )
        ),
        "ID",
        If(
            SortDescending1,
            Ascending,
            Descending
        )
    )),
    (SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'ATP Request Change'],
            Lower('Initiator Name'.Email) = Lower(User().Email) Or IsBlank('Initiator Name'.Email) Or Lower('Control Owner A'.Email) = Lower(User().Email) Or Lower('SOX OG Approver'.Value) = Lower(User().Email) Or Lower('SOX Testing Approver'.Value) = Lower(User().Email) && StartsWith(
                Control,
                TextSearchBox1.Text
            )
        ),
        "ID",
        If(
            SortDescending1,
            Ascending,
            Descending
        )
    ) && 'ATP Request Change'.Status = Dropdown1.Selected.Result)
)
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This portion doesn't make any sense:

```
&& 'ATP Request Change'.Status = Dropdown1.Selected.Result
```

Is this supposed to be part of your filter logic?